# /dev mounted as readonly

Tags: drivers

i am trying to write a device driver for my gps module. somehow the linux os when loaded to my arm board have /dev directory read only.
when i try to do a "vi /dev/gps" it says file is read only.

due to this reason my application program can't open the /dev/gps.

Anybody know what is the problem here. May be i am too vague.

Comment: You *are* doing this as root, right? What is the output of `mount`?

Comment: Have you mounted devfs yet? Do you run a with a read-only root filesystem? Why on earth are you trying to run an editor on the device file?

Comment: You can't run a text editor against a character device.  You might be able to run it against a block device like /dev/fd0 as I have done in the past, but that will read in the whole block device (floppy in this case) into memory and the text editor may still have issues reading/writing.  For a character device, try using cat to monitor it's output.  That works with my GPS.

Comment: Also, post the output of `id`, `ls -l /dev/gps`, and `ls -lL /dev/gps` if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Running `ls -l /dev/gps` will show you the actual permissions on the device file (probably not read-only).

Seeing as this is in fact a device file, you won't be able to open it in a text editor (for obvious reasons).